# How make natural join in two list in java?

Tags: java

[image]

I want to make `C2` from `L1 natural join L1`

[image]

and `C3` from `L2 natural join L2`

Is this possible in java easily if I load `L1` in a Arraylist?
Suppose,

```
ArrayList<Integer> L1 = new ArrayList<>();
L1.addAll(2,3,4,5,6,6);

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> L2 = new ArrayList<>();
L2.addAll('2,3','2,4','2,5','2,6','3,4','3,5','3,6','4,5','4,6','5,6'); //syntax are not accurate, I use this for understanding what I want.
```

Comment: please give an example of what you have tried and then stackoverflow will try to help you

Comment: Express your question using words, not images.

Comment: L1.addAll(2,3,4,5,6,6); ? addAll method take param as collection

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> L1 = new ArrayList<>();
        L1.add(2);
        L1.add(3);
        L1.add(4);
        L1.add(5);
        L1.add(6);
        L1.add(7);
        L1.add(8);
        L1.add(9);

        ArrayList<String> L2=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<L1.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<L1.size();j++)
            {
                L2.add(L1.get(i)+","+L1.get(j));
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<L2.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(L2.get(i));
        }
```

> **OUTPUT**

```
2,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
2,7
2,8
2,9
3,4
3,5
3,6
3,7
3,8
3,9
4,5
4,6
4,7
4,8
4,9
5,6
5,7
5,8
5,9
6,7
6,8
6,9
7,8
7,9
8,9
```

Comment: Your method works, but it also adds items from the first list to itself, meaning that the first one is `2,2` instead of `2,3`, and it will repeat through the list. Edit, looks good now.

Comment: @sorifiend edited please check

Comment: Looks good now. @alhelal I don't know what you mean by a natural method, but this is about as good an answer as you will get because what you are for is quite specific behaviour.

Comment: @sorifiend thank you

Comment: Does it work for making `C3`. see my second image.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Yes. The book name also visible in the image.

Comment: @alhelal is working as u want sir

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki it is not issue whether it is data mining or not. I actually asked this as a programming problem.

Comment: @alhelal ok  i just saing that is my aswer is working or not

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki in your answer making `C3` produces duplicate value.